# TypeScript Extend namespace

Tags: typescript, oop, namespaces

I am trying to find out how to use extention of namespaces.
let's say, I have namespace a

```
namespace a {
    export type x= number
    export type foo= () => void
}
```

and I want to use it in two other namespaces, without copy-pasting.
something like

```
namespace b & a{
    export type y= number
}

namespace c & a{
    export type z= boolean
}
```

like in ts types.

There is nothing in namespace documentation that answers my question.
Any help would be very much appriciated!

Things that i have tried:

1)

```
namespace b{
    export namespace a {
        export type x = number
        export type foo= () => void
    }
    export type y = number
}
```

which is not allows reuse of a in c.

2)

```
namespace b{
    export type x = a.x
    export type t = a.t
    export type y = number
}
```

which is better, but still awfull, if I have a lot of types exported in a.

3. tried with types,
   and it works, but the use is less beautiful

```
type a  = {
    x: number,
    t: () => void
}
type b = a&{
    y: number
}


const i :b.x = 1 // compilation error.
const i :b["x"] = 1 // works but not as beautiful as b.x
```

Comment: If all you're doing in namespaces is exporting consts, maybe you should use plain objects instead like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxj7bw) shows.  Does that work for you? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, could you [edit] the code in your question to show the use cases it doesn't work for?

Comment: You are right, it was confusing, tried to simplify. I need to export types, not consts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing `const`s with `type`s

---

#### if you intentionally export `const`s

you can define `i` as

```
const i = b.x
```

and it will be typed as `const i: 1`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=14#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEIkG8BQTtIgDxgHsAnAFyXkOCnLyQF4kBGAbix3yLIqpqXMYAKAJQMAfOiQBfDDIyhIsBMgBG6dtk4lylarQYoAdHg24C2nnv4GQh0qa3ddfAJ4GATLIwZn5AJYGKsZIAPQhPGAwfgA2IKR+VLjExCSG3s6E0RCG0YQA5oJ+omFIuXlQzEA)

---

#### otherwise

you can export types

```
namespace a {
    export type x = 1;
    export type t = () => { }
}

namespace b {
    export type x = a.x
    export type t = a.t
    export type y = 2
}

const i: b.x = 1 // here you can use it to type variable
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEIkG8BQTtIgDxgHsAnAFyVIE8Zk8kBeJARgG4sd8iyLrlzGAFAEoGAPnRIAvhmkZQkWAmQAjdO2ycS5KjSR1GIAHR51uAlp67+KQ6VObuO5JQZIATDIwZ4hYFHIAlgBcSMrGrkxIAPRRSD5gMAEANiCkAb64xMQkhl4+foRJEIZJhADmAgEiMUilZVDMQA)

---

#### or

you can define the `b.x` as `typeof a.x`

```
namespace b {
    export type x = typeof a.x
    export type t = typeof a.t
    export type y = 2
}

const i: b.x = 1 // and once again you'll be able to type `i`
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEIkG8BQTtIgDxgHsAnAFyXkOCnLyQF4kBGAbix3yLIqpqXMYAKAJQMAfOiQBfDDIyhIsBMgBG6dtk4lypAJ4xkdRnoOEAZigB0eDbgLb++5AMemLIS6VtbuJ5LoYkACZZDAxKanIASwAuJBVrQKYkAHoUnjAYKIAbEFIoqlxiYhJLMIioQmyIS2zCAHNBKNE0pDr6qGYgA)